# How to run pip on windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip

How to run pip on windows?

I understand, that it may be very silly question, but all guides, entire web have same:

```
$ pip install <package>
```

But where should I find this "$"? It is not Windows console. It is not Python console. It is not different combinations of them. Where should I find this magical "$" on Windows?

Comment: $ is in terminal on linux and mac OS's: http://linuxcommand.org/images/Screenshot-Terminal.png

Comment: Thank you, but there is a lot of words about "it works on windows", and no example "how it works on windows" :-) That is my question, how run it on Windows.

Comment: Try easy_install. It basically is the same thing and works in windows.

Comment: @AHuman what for is this useful topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows about "how to install" if it is not possible to use?

Comment: Also PyCharm somehow use it successfully and even gives UI for that. So, there have to be terminal command, I guess.

Comment: Run it in your command line. Win+R, type `cmd` and hit enter. That brings up the console. Type `pip install <package>` and ta-da.

Comment: @Arkady I was showing you something that I use, that is really easy to set up. All you have to do is go into your terminal and type: `easy_install ______`

Comment: @AHuman `easy_install` is like pip's little brother. `easy_install pip` and use pip :)

Comment: @AdamSmith "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
As I wrote in my post, all combinations of trying to run it from win console or python console didn't gave result.

Comment: @Arkady you may need to add it to your path then. IIRC `pip` installs in your python/site-packages folder but I may be wrong. EDIT: I'm wrong, see my further comment.

Comment: @AdamSmith, I already checked that, there exists pip package, but it has no executable file.

Comment: @Arkady oops it's `C:\Python\scripts`

Comment: @Arkady That does work to use easy_install to install pip.

Comment: @AHuman he's already installed `pip`. He's asking how to USE it, not how to install it. I misunderstood as well.

Comment: @AHuman, I found "easy_install.py" in my site-packages directory, and run it, it works. :-) Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you install pip (via `get-pip.py` or etc) it installs into your python directory in the subfolder `\Lib\site-packages`. It also puts a `pip.exe` in your `%python%\scripts` folder. If you add `C:\python-install-directory\scripts` to your PATH you should be able to run it from the command line:

```
$ pip install <package>
```

The `$` you see is the standard *nix terminal. Windows uses a `>` after the working directory, *nix uses a `$`. It is safely ignored.

Comment: Sometimes on Windows you also need to run the command console with Administrator privileges. I have no idea when this is required, only that if running it with user privileges leads to problems, it's worth trying to run as Administrator.

Answer (score 6):

Try this it helped me to solve the problem

```
py -m pip <your command>
```

"-m" should handle all your path related problems